# @EnableFeignClients package scan - spring boot

Tags: regex, spring-boot, package, netflix-feign

I have annotated spring boot application with Feign Client

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients({"com.ms.Foo1.api", "com.ms.Foo2.api",
"com.ms.Foo3.api", "com.ms.Foo4.api", "com.ms.Foo5.api", "com.ms.Foo6.api",
"com.ms.Foo7.api", "com.ms.Foo8.api", "com.ms.Foo9.api", "com.ms.Foo10.api"})
public class AnalyticsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

everything working fine, AS I just modify the bases packages. its start scanning package outside the api.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients({"com.ms.*.api"})
public class AnalyticsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

I am expecting that `@EnableFeignClients({"com.ms.*.api"})` will scan only clients inside the api but it start scanning outside the api package as well.

what I need to change ? or can we apply regex here instead of mention every package ?

Comment: *everything working fine, AS I just modify the bases packages. its start scanning package outside the api.* - could you clarify what do you mean by *I just modify the bases packages*?

Comment: @star67 Instead of mentioned all package in `@EnableFeignClients`, I just put `{"com.ms.*.api"}` its equal to `basePackages ={"com.ms.*.api"}`

Comment: As the name implies it is the `basePackage` i.e. where it starts scanning from. It doesn't take an (ant-style) regular expression it is the starting point for scanning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex filter on @ComponentScan like this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ms",
     includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern="com.ms.*.api"))
public class AnalyticsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

But @EnableFeignClients haven't this feature. The only thing you can do is:

```
@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = "com.ms")
public class AnalyticsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```